# How to convert UTF16LE to string C#?

Tags: c#, utf-16

I have a file with text in UTF16LE like so

> feff 0074 0065 0073 0074

which is basically

> test

What I am trying to is to read that file:

```
         using (FileStream stream = File.Open(fileName, FileMode.Open))
                {
                    byte[] b = new byte[stream.Length];
                    Encoding u16LE = Encoding.Unicode;
                    arrRaw.Add(u16LE.GetString(b));
                }
```

After that im starting reading those string array in another function:

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

And so the output of that is just hieroglyphs. I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Moreover I was trying to start reading from the third byte in that array, but the result was the same

```
public static string Utf16ToUtf8Initial(string utf16String)
        {

            string utf8String = String.Empty;

            byte[] utf16Bytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(utf16String);
            byte[] utf8Bytes = Encoding.Convert(Encoding.Unicode, Encoding.UTF8, utf16Bytes);


            utf8String = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(utf8Bytes);
            return utf8String;
        }
```

Comment: You're using UTF8 for UTF16, that's the wrong way I guess. Do not use UTF8 at all, all you need is Unicode that is UTF16

Comment: If the file is small, File.ReadAllText should do https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readalltext?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: Please insert code as text, not image.

Comment: String uses one of the Unicode Encodings, when storing in memory. However I do not know wich one, and it could be subject to change/variable settings anyway. There is no point caring about the Encoding of String in memory. You only need to bother with that when reading from or writing to something that is outside of code.

Comment: @Soonts Im gonna use very large files next. It's just a simple test

Comment: @IlyaPribil For large ones, use File.OpenText https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.opentext?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: @IlyaPribil Or create StreamReader explicitly: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamreader.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8#System_IO_StreamReader__ctor_System_String_